# Cannot create an additional database in Oracle 18c XE

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, oracle-18c

Creating a new database in Oracle 18c XE throws this error, does this mean that I can **only** use the database created by the installation?

> ORA-00442: Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) single instance
> violation error
>
> ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments:
> [OSDEP_INTERNAL], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
>
> ORA-27302: failure occurred at: sxesingleins ORA-27303: additional
> information: environment variable ORACLE_SID should be XE only

Comment: In Oracle you rarely need additional instances (=database). You typically just create a new schema/user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Licensing Restrictions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinw/licensing-restrictions.html)

> Oracle Database XE restricts itself to only one installation per
>   logical environment. The logical environment can either be a virtual
>   host such as a VM or container, or a physical host. If more than one
>   Oracle Database XE installation is attempted to be started in such a
>   logical environment, an "ORA-00442: Oracle Database Express Edition
>   (XE) single instance violation error" is raised and the database will
>   not start.